# Bootstrap datetime picker adding months instead of days

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have the following code snippet in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tanjaforsberg/sdyoxx2r/2/). I'm trying to add given number as days to the calendar.

HTML Code:

```
<input id="firstDate"/>
<input type="hidden" value="11" id="days">
<br/>
<input id="secondDate"/>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var pickerOptsGeneral = {
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
autoclose: true,
minView: 2,
maxView: 2
};

 $('#firstDate')
.datetimepicker(pickerOptsGeneral)
.on('changeDate', function(ev){
var days = document.getElementById("days").value;
 var oldDate = new Date(ev.date);
 var newDate = new Date();
 newDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + days);

 secondDate.val(newDate.getDate()+"/"+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+newDate.getFullYear());
 secondDate.datetimepicker('update');
});
var secondDate = $('#secondDate').datetimepicker(pickerOptsGeneral);
</script>
```

The above code is adding months instead of days. If i select the date

`01/06/2017` the output will be `19/9/2017`

If I hardcode the date:

```
     newDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + 11);
```

This will give me the output I want. Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
var pickerOptsGeneral = {
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    minView: 2,
    maxView: 2
};
$('#firstDate')
  .datetimepicker(pickerOptsGeneral)
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
     var days = parseInt(document.getElementById("days").value);
     var oldDate = $("#firstDate").data("datetimepicker").getDate();
     var oldDateOriginal = new Date(oldDate);
     var  newDate = new Date(oldDateOriginal);
     newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);
     secondDate.val(newDate.getDate()+"/"+(newDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+newDate.getFullYear());
     secondDate.datetimepicker('update');
});
var secondDate = $('#secondDate').datetimepicker(pickerOptsGeneral);
```

JSFfiddle link for same -  http://jsfiddle.net/sdyoxx2r/9/

Comment: Glad it helps :) @Tanja Forsberg

Comment: There is one complication though. If I select date `01/08/2017` the result is `12/6/2017`. It increments day only. Can you please check on the jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Tanja Forsberg i have update my ans please check it.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value of `<input type="hidden" value="11" id="days" />` it will return value as string.

So you need to convert value of days from string to integer .

```
var pickerOptsGeneral = {
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
autoclose: true,
minView: 2,
maxView: 2
};
$('#firstDate').datetimepicker(pickerOptsGeneral).on('changeDate',function(ev){
 var days        = parseInt($('#days').val());
 var oldDate = new Date(ev.date);
 var newDate = new Date();
 newDate.setDate(oldDate.getDate() + days);
 secondDate.val(newDate.getDate()+"/"+newDate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+newDate.getFullYear());
 secondDate.datetimepicker('update');
});
var secondDate = $('#secondDate').datetimepicker(pickerOptsGeneral);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have another bug mentioned in above comment.

Comment: try this `newDate.setMonth(oldDate.getMonth(),oldDate.getDate()+days);`